# how do i run loops simultaneously in gitlab-ci?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following script in my gitlab-ci and will like to run the loops same time, anyone knows a great way to do this? so that they both run at same time

**NOTE** the job is a manual job and am looking for a single button click to loop through all the packages in the bash script as shown below

```
    when: manual
    script:
        - |-
            for PACKAGE in name1 name2; do
                export IMAGE="$CI_REGISTRY/$GITLAB_REPO/$PACKAGE:${BUILD_TAG}"
                docker build -t ${IMAGE} -f $PACKAGE/Dockerfile .
                docker push ${IMAGE}
            done
```

currently it runs first for `name1` and then after that is finished then runs for `name2`. I will like to run both at same exact time since there is no dependency

Here is what i tried from an answer on SO => (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475/138406)

```
    when: manual
    script:
        - |-
            task(){
                export IMAGE="$CI_REGISTRY/$GITLAB_REPO/$1:${BUILD_TAG}"
                docker build -t ${IMAGE} -f $1/Dockerfile .
                docker push ${IMAGE}         
            }
            for PACKAGE in name1 name2; do
                task "$PACKAGE" &
            done
```

This works in regular bash script but when i used it with gitlab-ci, it doesnt run as expected and does not even run any of the commands and just succeeds the job instantly

Anyone willing to help on where the issue is and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Research "how to run ... simultaneously in bash" and you'll get the same answer.

Comment: if you know answer, can you post answer below?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your use case, I'd suggest you rather "parallelize" the build **using several dedicated GitLab-CI jobs**, rather than *using several bash jobs* in a single GitLab-CI job.

Proof-of-concept:

```yaml
stages:
  - push

.push-template:
  stage: push
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    IMAGE: "${CI_REGISTRY}/${GITLAB_REPO}/${PACKAGE}:${BUILD_TAG}"
    # where ${PACKAGE} should be provided by the child jobs...
  before_script: |
    if [ -z "${PACKAGE}" ]; then
      echo 'Error: variable PACKAGE is undefined' >&2
      false
    fi
    # just for completeness, this may be required:
    echo "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" | docker login -u "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" --password-stdin "${CI_REGISTRY}"
  script:
    - docker build -t "${IMAGE}" -f "${PACKAGE}/Dockerfile" .
    - docker push "${IMAGE}"
    - docker logout "${CI_REGISTRY}" || true

push-name1:
  extends: .push-template
  variables:
    PACKAGE: name1

push-name2:
  extends: .push-template
  variables:
    PACKAGE: name2
```

See the [.gitlab-ci.yml reference manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) for details on the `extends` keyword.

Comment: issue with this approach is i lose the one button click to run that job, now this will be 2 jobs..this is a manual job fyi...so if it is possible to do in bash, that is what am after

Comment: OK, can you be more specific on your constraint and add details in your question? BTW, I definitely believe that it won't be possible to do this in bash, because e.g. you might have `$(nproc) = 1` on gitlab.com, if you see what I mean… while GitLab CI will let you have a much larger parallelism level by using several jobs.

Comment: the `when: manual` is the only constraint..and this is with self-hosted gitlab...so not gitlab.com

Comment: OK but can't you mark several jobs as `when: manual`? this way, you'll have these several jobs run when you see fit. (in the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually), I don't see anything that prevents from having several manual jobs).

Comment: But maybe you're interested in having several manual jobs, with the ability to run these *n* jobs by clicking only *once* on a button? (not on *n* buttons)

Comment: so what is purpose of parallel jobs? if i have to click buttons to run the jobs? my use-case is one click runs the job to build both packages

Comment: why cant bash do this? probably more interested in that...will be the best if bash can work as expected

Comment: My suggestion was just related to the fact I didn't know the number of packages you wanted to build at once: if it's only 2 and each job script runs on a 2+ vCPU, your overall use case can indeed be addressed using a mere bash parallelism…(in this case, my answer doesn't fully address your question); but if you build 2+ packages and the job scripts just run on a 1 vCPU, then your use case would scale better with my suggestion, I believe.

Comment: there can be like 10 packages, which is why bash will be the best, if possible ofcourse...am after being able to just click once and have all packages build in parallel

Comment: OK…, but I have no time anymore to extend my answer for now, I'll try to do this on the WE; or maybe another SO user will post another alternative meanwhile :)

Comment: yeah will wait till WE, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

> just succeeds the job instantly

That is what running in the background means - it means that the main process will continue instantly. You have to **wait** for background processes to finish.

```
    - |-
        task(){
            export IMAGE="$CI_REGISTRY/$GITLAB_REPO/$1:${BUILD_TAG}"
            docker build -t ${IMAGE} -f $1/Dockerfile .
            docker push ${IMAGE}         
        }
        for PACKAGE in name1 name2; do
            task "$PACKAGE" &
        done
        wait
```

But that will not catch any errors, which will result in problems going undetected. You would have to collect pids and wait on the individually:

```
...
        childs=""
        for package in name1 name2; do
            task "$package" &
            childs="$childs $!"
        done
        for pid in $childs; do
            if ! wait "$pid"; then
                echo "Process with pid=$pid failed"
                kill $childs
                wait
                exit 1
            fi
        done
```

But anyway, this is cumbersome and it's reinventing the wheel. Install GNU `xargs` (or even better `parallel`) and make sure your docker container has bash shell. Then, just export the function and run it in subprocess with xargs:

```
...
export -f task
printf "%s\n" name1 name2 | xargs -P0 -d '\n' bash -xeuo pipefail -c 'func "$@"' --
```

You may want to research https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html or even https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html .

Definitely, instead of writing long scripts in .gitlab-ci yaml file - move it all a dedicated script file, so that you can test the run locally. Check your scripts with shellcheck. And anyway - using `docker-compose` might also be simpler.

Anyway, this is all odd and *for sure* I wouldn't do it that way anyway. Gitlab-runner is already the tool that gives you parallelization - it runs multiple jobs in the same stage in parallel. Just run two tasks.

```
 .todo:
    script:
        export IMAGE="$CI_REGISTRY/$GITLAB_REPO/${CI_JOB_NAME}:${BUILD_TAG}"
        docker build -t ${IMAGE} -f ${CI_JOB_NAME}/Dockerfile .
        docker push ${IMAGE}   

 name1:
    extends: .todo
 name2:
    extends: .todo
```

Such approach will give your pipeline visible indication over what specific task failed, so you wouldn't need to scroll through mangled unreadable logs of two processes running in parallel. Just one job with one task.

Comment: +1 for this comprehensive answer (see also [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70282117/9164010) to see more "boilerplate" with the GitLab-CI multi-job solution :) − BTW @KamilCuk it seems there's a typo? (`$${CI_JOB_NAME}` → `${CI_JOB_NAME}`)